# What's the difference between `asset` and `extended_asset`?

Tags: smart-contract

tl;dr: I just wanted to reuse a "token currency type" with symbol and precisions validations out-of-the-box.

If I’m implementing “token” currency in my contracts, which one should I use?

I’m just asking that because looks like `eosjs` verifies `get_currency_stats` for `asset` and do not for `extended_asset` and I don’t need that verification. Actually it breaks my app because my contract has a completely different structure of the regular `eosio.token`...

Answer (score 4):

Asset and Symbol default to eosio.token and both have precision.  The asset has an additional amount.

Extended asset and symbol are the same except they both add a contract account.  Any custom token will need the extended version.

Both extended and regular version will query get_currency_stats in order to find precision (cached in RAM).  At present, it will try to verify precision because that is very important in how the transaction is encoded in binary and required when signing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Just adding this issue and their answer in git: https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs/issues/122#issuecomment-393942526

Answer (score 1):

Apart from some helpful additives (max amount, precision, checks for valid symbols,...) it stores more than the asset class. It keeps the owner of the asset (given by an account). For EOS it is account `eosio.token`, which is the default account for the `asset` constructor. ([Reference](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cpp/reference#extended-asset))

A list of some examples where arguments might be *optional* is given. The extended_asset can be constructed by either:

> `extended_asset(amount, *extended_symbol*)` e.g. `extended_asset(asset(150), extended symbol(S(4, EOS))`
>
> or
>
> `extended_asset(asset, *account*)` e.g. `extended_asset(asset(150))` for eosio.token

and we have

> - `asset(amount, *symbol*)` e.g. `asset(150)` for eosio.token
> - `extended_symbol(symbol, *account*)` e.g. `extended_symbol(symbol, N(eosio.token))`
> - `symbol_type(symbol_name)` e.g. `construct with S(4, EOS)`
> - `S(P,X)` a macro that takes precision and a string and converts it into a symbol

In total all 3 are neeeded: amount, symbol, account. Since your token is not owned by account `eosio.token` you should use `extended_asset`.